# Is panchromatic usable for supervised classification schemes in R or QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, image-classification, worldview-2

I am using Worldview-2 and Worldview-3 panchromatic images from 2019. I am looking at discrete topographical features which are easily delineated as polygon ROIs. However, I only have this panchromatic imagery to work with.

The goal for this project is to delineate tindividual, discrete topographic features as polygons in QGIS, use them as training files for classification, and use a classification method to identify topography within the image in R or in QGIS.

I have tried classifying the images using tools such as SCP, and functions in the Orfeo Toolbox. Although, it seems all of these tools require multiscpectral imagery.

Is image classification only possible with multispectral imagery, or can images be classified using panchromatic imagery? What tools allow for the latter?

Comment: I did not quite understand what you are trying to do, but for a "classic" classification you need multispectral imagery because you basically "measure the spectral reflectance" which you can not do with a panchromatic image.

Comment: Why would you use panchromatic imagery to identify topographical features? Why not use a DEM which are widely available globally? You will not get adequate representation of geomorphometric features using a panchromatic image, even if they are visually identifiable. A z value that represents relief opens up a variety of analytical approaches that are not currently feasible in with your data.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback - I was able to find a relatively easy solution. I derived gray-level co-occurrence matrices (GLCM) for my image using a variety of GLCM input parameters. Once I determined the GLCM-calculated textural features and input parameters which displayed significant distinction between ROI groups (2 distinct groups), I coded those GLCM textural features as input 'predictor' variables in two machine learning algorithms in R. This method used only panchromatic imagery and OS software for highly accurate classification!